# Netbeans 6.7 PHP - How to highlight PHP Code in HTML files?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans6.7

Is there any way to tell Netbeans to highlight PHP code in HTML files? I am using Zend Framework, where a lot of PHP code is included in the view files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks, but i have found the solutions.

You can set in the Options Screen - Misc - Files. The Type associated with .phtml. After switching it to php it works.

Comment: +1 : Oh, I really missed this one :-( Thanks for the info ;-)

Comment: thanks, your hint helped me to set the association for *.tml files (tapestry markup language) +1

Comment: I coudn't find Misc in options... Can you please specify the exact steps to do this.